# django invalid syntax(urls.py line 7

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

this is the mysite/urls.py from a tutorial in making a website with python and django
mysiteurls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover() 
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
)
```

When I try to hit my url I get invalid syntax. What's it not liking?

Essentially I want the view to populate a template XML file I built.
please help am creating a website and came across this error in my urls
here is my code

```
blog/urls.py

from django.conf.urls import patterns,url
from django.views.generic import ListView
from blog.models import Post
```

i get an invalid syntax error on my code when i call it on my localbrowser

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^',ListView.as_view(
  queryset=Post.objects.all()order_by("-date")[:10],
  template_name="blog.html")),
)
```

please help am new to the program

Comment: it worked but defined another error Indentation Error
unexpected indent (urls.py, line 1)

Answer (score 4):

In the following line, the code is missing `.`:

```
queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:10],
#                          ^
```